# check if the group id or element is found the column list in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
data = {

    'org_id' :[4,73,6,77,21,36,40,22,21,30,31],
    'flag': [['4', '73'],['73'],['6', '77'],['77'],['21'],['36', '36'],['40'],['22', '41'],['21'],['22', '30'],['31', '31']],
    'r_id' : [4,4,6,6,20,20,20,22,28,28,28]


    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

required data frame to be like below,

```
data = {

    'org_id' :[4,73,6,77,21,36,40,22,21,30,31],
    'flag': [['4', '73'],['73'],['6', '77'],['77'],['21'],['36', '36'],['40'],['22', '41'],['21'],['22', '30'],['31', '31']],
    'r_id' : [4,4,6,6,20,20,20,22,28,28,28],
    'is_foundin_org_id': ['yes','yes','yes','yes','NO','NO','NO','yes','NO','NO','NO']

    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df2
```

output data frame

```
Out[115]: 
    org_id      flag  r_id is_foundin_org_id
0        4   [4, 73]     4               yes
1       73      [73]     4               yes
2        6   [6, 77]     6               yes
3       77      [77]     6               yes
4       21      [21]    20                NO
5       36  [36, 36]    20                NO
6       40      [40]    20                NO
7       22  [22, 41]    22               yes
8       21      [21]    28                NO
9       30  [22, 30]    28                NO
10      31  [31, 31]    28                NO
```

Need to identify after grouping by r_id whether r_id is present in the grouped rows of r_id, eg. when I group by 4 is found in one of the rows of org_id, hence i mark yes  for the group 4, similarly for 20 is not found in the org_id column, hence i mark No for all the 20s group. Thanking you.

Comment: what is flag used for, can you remove it if it is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
d = {True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}
df['is_foundin_org_id'] = (df.org_id.eq(df.r_id).groupby(df.r_id)
                             .transform('max').map(d))

Out[1549]:
    org_id      flag  r_id is_foundin_org_id
0   4       [4, 73]   4     Yes
1   73      [73]      4     Yes
2   6       [6, 77]   6     Yes
3   77      [77]      6     Yes
4   21      [21]      20    No
5   36      [36, 36]  20    No
6   40      [40]      20    No
7   22      [22, 41]  22    Yes
8   21      [21]      28    No
9   30      [22, 30]  28    No
10  31      [31, 31]  28    No
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

```
df['is_found'] = np.where(df['org_id'].eq(df['r_id']) # check if the ids are equal
                              .groupby(df['r_id'])    # group by r_id
                              .transform('any'),      # if True occurs within the groups
                          'yes', 'no')
```

Output:

```
    org_id      flag  r_id is_found
0        4   [4, 73]     4      yes
1       73      [73]     4      yes
2        6   [6, 77]     6      yes
3       77      [77]     6      yes
4       21      [21]    20       no
5       36  [36, 36]    20       no
6       40      [40]    20       no
7       22  [22, 41]    22      yes
8       21      [21]    28       no
9       30  [22, 30]    28       no
10      31  [31, 31]    28       no
```

Comment: I wonder if it's possible that the first `r_id` could be `73` instead of `4`

Comment: @ragaelc, IIUC, 73 could be a group as well

Comment: @rafaelc per OP's *after groupby `r_id`*, so that case would yield two `no`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yea! I had interpreted just like you, but then this `flag` column is throwing me off haha

Answer (score 1):

## `Numpy` and `pandas.factorize`

This may seem convoluted.  But I'm using `Numpy` and keeping everything **O(n)**

Get arrays because I'll use them more than once

```
a = df.r_id.to_numpy()
b = df.org_id.to_numpy()
```

Factorizing something identifies each unique value with an integer starting with zero.  `pandas.factorize` will return a tuple of `(factorized_integer_representation, unique_values)`.  What's great about the factorization is that I can use those integers as positions within the unique values array to reproduce the original array. Namely `r[i]` using the `r` and `i` below.

I could've also used `numpy.unique` with the argument `return_inverse` to get the same arrays, **BUT** `pandas.factorize` doesn't sort the unique values and that is an order of **O(log(n))** that we can save by not using.  For larger data, `pandas.factorize` is the winner.

I'll create a holding array that will house the boolean values on whether our **any** condition is satisfied for each unique value.  `numpy.logical_or.at` is the function we use to see if any values from `a == b` is `True` within the specified indices in `i`.

I'll demonstrate after the code below.

```
i, r = pd.factorize(a)
o = np.zeros(len(r), bool)
np.logical_or.at(o, i, a == b)

df.assign(is_found=np.where(o, 'Yes', 'No')[i])

    org_id      flag  r_id is_found
0        4   [4, 73]     4      Yes
1       73      [73]     4      Yes
2        6   [6, 77]     6      Yes
3       77      [77]     6      Yes
4       21      [21]    20       No
5       36  [36, 36]    20       No
6       40      [40]    20       No
7       22  [22, 41]    22      Yes
8       21      [21]    28       No
9       30  [22, 30]    28       No
10      31  [31, 31]    28       No
```

---

## Details

```
a == b

array([True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False])
```

---

`r` are the unique values

```
r

array([ 4,  6, 20, 22, 28])
```

---

`i` are the indices

```
i

array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

---

So `r[i]` reproduces `a`

```
r[i]

array([ 4,  4,  6,  6, 20, 20, 20, 22, 28, 28, 28])
```

---

Now we start with a base array `o` of all False, one for each unique value

```
array([False, False, False, False, False])
```

And for each position in `i`, we check if the corresponding value in `a == b` is `True`.

```
#  i, a == b ->  0,  True <4 == 4>
#                0, False <4 != 73>
#                     ↓    1,  True <6 == 6>
#                     ↓    1, False <6 != 77>
#                     ↓         ↓    2, False <20 != 21>
#                     ↓         ↓    2, False <20 != 36>
#                     ↓         ↓    2, False <20 != 40>
#                     ↓         ↓         ↓    3,  True <22 == 22>
#                     ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓    4, False <28 != 21>
#                     ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓    4, False <28 != 30>
#                     ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓    4, False <28 != 31>
#  At least 1 True    ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓
#  o         -> [    True,     True,    False,     True,    False]
```

Swap `Yes`|`No` instead of `True`|`False`

```
#  o                         -> [    True,     True,    False,     True,    False]
#  np.where(o, 'Yes', 'No')  -> [   'Yes',    'Yes',     'No',    'Yes',     'No']
```

And slice it with `i` to produce an array of the same length as original with the appropriate value for each corresponding value in the unique values array.

```
np.where(o, 'Yes', 'No')[i]

['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No']
```

Comment: I like your numpy solution :) +1

Comment: Thx @AndyL. Updated with more details.

Comment: wow, nice and detailed explanation. I tagged this as my favorite. Thumbs up!